# What does "joke security" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've come across it in the 7th episode of the 3rd season of *Rick and Morty*. Here is the context:

Agent Rick and Agent Rick 2 are working as security guards, or police officers, or something like this. Another character asks if someone won an election. Agent Rick says, "Yeah, it was a blowout."  As he says this, he opens an airlock, causing the character to be blown out into space.

Then we see the following exchange:

> Agent Rick 2: I would hardly call it a blow out. It was almost close enough to trigger a recount.
>
> Agent Rick: Jesus. what are you **joke security** now, too?

Comment: Are there two agents called Rick?  Rick and and Rick 2? Where does Morty come into this? Has someone made a joke in the recent conversation?   Don't forget we don't all watch  TV drama series.

Comment: It's probably some localized gag but again, more context would be necessary.

Comment: The context is Morty won the presidency .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, *blowout* typically means:

> **blowout** *noun*
>
> 4: an easy or one-sided victory

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blowout

But in this case, Agent Rick is making joke (a pun), since "blowout" could also describe what happens to the other character as he's shot out of the airlock.

Agent Rick 2 then corrects Agent Rick: "I would hardly call it a blowout."  This ruins the joke. Agent Rick is annoyed that Agent Rick 2 has ruined his joke.

Now let's look at the line with this full context.

Start with the simpler: "What, are you security, now?"

In this context, a phrase like "are you security" means *are you working as a security guard*, or, *are you responsible for security*.

So what would *joke security* mean?  It's not a common phrase, but it's an obvious variation on common constructions like *joke police*, *grammar police*, *fashion police*, etc.  These phrases are all used facetiously to criticize someone for inappropriately *policing* something they're not responsible for.  For example, "who are you, the fashion police?" would mean *who are you to criticize, or try to control the way I dress?*

Likewise, *joke security* would police jokes, that is, inappropriately try to stop people from making humorous remarks.

So, in this case, "what are you joke security now, too?" specifically means *I know that you are, in reality, a security guard; why are you also trying to police my joke telling?*

Comment: I downvoted because we are waiting for context.  As you yourself say, "Without context, it's pretty hard to tell." So why are you telling?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica, your vote is yours to cast.  To my mind, the point of this site is to provide useful information to English language learners.  Full context is a necessary part of "useful information."  Ideally that context would be provided in the question.  But if I can provide it in the answer, that seems good enough.  Thinking about it more, I suppose a better approach would have been to edit the question.  I'll do that now.